# Not getting tr to work with psuedo class :nth-child

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make it so that every other row in my table has a certain color. I've tried both :nth-child and :nth-of-type. But it doesnt work with the tr elements. I get it to work with th and td, resulting in every other column, but that's not what I'm looking for. I can't see why this isn't working Here's a replica of my code:

HTML:

```
    <html>
     <body>
      <div class="display-div">
        <table id="content-table">
           <tr>
              <td>Content</td>
              <td>Content</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Content</td>
              <td>Content</td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
              <td>Content</td>
              <td>Content</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
       </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

CSS:

```
.display-div {
overflow: scroll;
}

#content-table {
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
position: relative;
border-collapse: collapse;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
background-color: black;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r0q9a4p6/ I've check that it works. Is that what you need?

Comment: @VanTho Weird. That doesn't work for me. Might the reason be that it is my JS that creates the tr elements? Thx

Comment: I think you shoud check the css in the browser debugger. Maybe another css has overwrite it. How about adding `background-color: black !important;`, `!important` will overwrite other normal css

Comment: No rules overwriting the styles. !important didn't work either.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @HenrikKnudsen did you downvote my answer? if so may I know why.

Comment: @Manjuboyz no i didnt, i up-voted it. Someone else must have for some weird reason..

Answer (score 0):

I did this sometime ago, you can try something like this. This will get you started, I even worked on adding different `color` for columns too, since it is not your requirement I have removed that part.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
     
      $("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "LightBlue");
      $("table#id2 tr:odd td").css("background-color", "LightYellow");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="id2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**OR**

you can this in a simple way like this:

```
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

**If you need only in CSS then:**

```css
 tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
    tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```

```html
<table id="id2" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What would the non-jQuery variant of this look like? Thx

Comment: I expected you may ask that, I have added new code check and let me know!

Comment: I'll get back to you in a couple of hours when i get back from work

Comment: I didnt get it to work no. I ended up using an if statement and setting classes with desired background colors using the modulus operator to seperate even from odd. Thx for the help though